# Is it possible to publish application in AppStore which will accept credit card payments?

Tags: iphone, app-store, credit-card, payment

My company provides eCommerce solution for our customers. We host their web site where their customers buy some stuff. Our eCommerce solution takes their credit card information and processes it via payment gateway.

Now we want to create iPhone app for our customers somewhat duplicating functionality of their web sites. Similar to what Amazon.com app does. Provide native interface to browse items and then have ability to purchase them (again, I think Amazon.com application does that).

But I was reading stories how Apple usually rejects such applications if product if not going via in-App purchases. Or is it only for digital stuff?

Any thoughts on how likely such app will be rejected or approved?

Comment: Questions about AAPL's business practices are not appropriate for StackOverflow.

Comment: Well... My development strategy is kind of depend on that. And I saw several very similar questions here already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many apps have been approved and many apps have been rejected. I don't believe it is limited to just digital stuff.

I believe its just depends who reviews your application. It doesn't seem like there is an official rule about it. I think if there is a good reason for credit cards instead of an in-app purchase then your more likely to pass apple's approval process.

But your guaranteed way of getting it approved is to make everything an in-app purchase, so if you can use in-app purchase then do it.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately in-app purchase is not an option. If they would not approve checkout process directly from application I would have to redirect users to our customers web-sites to finish process there...

Comment: Mayb you should display the products, add them to a cart, do whatever else your need to do. Then when they are checking out you pass all of that data as POST data to a webserver and then you open a UIWebView for them to finish the checkout process.

Comment: Yea, that's a way too. Basically use same web site mechanism to do checkout, but load it inside app. Interesting though, Amazon.com app definitely did it inside native UI.

Comment: Yeah, Amazon is a multi-million dolar company. They can do stuff that smaller companies cant. Apple wants to keep them as happy as possible, especially since they sell apple products. It seems like most the app's that use credit cards come from larger companies.

Answer (score 0):

"AT&T myWireless" app does exactly what you want.
Besides there are a lot of Credit Card Processing apps in the AppStore.

So in case your app is not approved you can always point out AT&T's app
and say "Hey, why can they do that and I don't??" 
and they can always reply... or not actually

Answer (score 0):

If the mobile solution is generic for so many mobile platforms like J2ME, Android, iPhone etc, then it does not make sense to change the payment mechanism for one platform alone. So InApp purchase may not be an option for most of the cases. I believe Apple understands it and approves the apps accordingly.